Angular Slickgrid - Filter
"How can I add a new operator in the selection of a Compound Filter, or is it possible to set a custom filter to work like the SQL LIKE Operator?
Example:
I have a column with the following data:
Title 100.001
Tile 100.002
Title 11.001
If I write in the filter %Ti%001%, I want it to return rows that start with 'Ti' and end with '001'."
"angular-slickgrid": "4.2.6"

create a custom filter or extend an existing one with TypeScript, there's plenty of docs and demos to show how to do that

https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/0ddfe033dcd0da4958bbd2b74605dd8792017f3c/src/app/examples/custom-inputFilter.ts
I don't know how to edit the above example so that the filter works like the SQL operator LIKE.
You wrote that I have to use the operator type OperatorType | OperatorString, but it doesn't contain the operator I want to use.

maybe try with the contains operator, however I don't know what type of backend service you're using but for sure the OData/GraphQL are never going to return what you're looking for. So I assume you'll have to either extend a backend service or create your own as well. I can maybe add a custom operator in the future but that will only be available for newer version (I'm about to ship v8.0) and the filter service still won't know what to do with a custom filter anyway, at least not with local filtering, this might work with a custom backend service, how did you plan to use this anyway?

I have a large list with similar data e.g Title 100.001, Title 001.100, Title 0.100.01 and so on. User type Ti%01 and return Title 100.001 and Title 0.100.01 because start Ti and end 01 like SQL LIKE OPERATOR. For now i don't know i can achieve it

you didn't mention which backend service you use but assuming that you use a modified (via extends) or a new backend service and you use the contains, you could have a condition that when the contains is used and the % char is found more than once then execute this xyz query string. if (operator === OperatorType.contains && searchValue.includes('%') { // modify query string }. You could probably use any other operator like equal and just check for % in search value and modify query string accordingly, in any case modifying the backend service seems like the only way to do it

actually, another way might be to simply modify the query string in the process callback. process: (query) => { if (query.includes('%') { // modify query string })} maybe use regex to retrieve the search value to change before returning the final query string. It might be easier to use but it's less flexible compare to modifying the actual backend service which would be safer too. Modifying the query string with process could end up with an invalid query string, so you have to be sure on how you modify it

I don't use a backend service, I use regular grid and i don't use pagination. I wasn't aware of this patent. I thought I could use a custom filter to solve my problem. I'll try using a backend service.

I provided a solution below that works with a local JSON dataset

You can provide a different list of compound operators via Compound Operator List (custom list)
but that was only introduced in Slickgrid-Universal v2.6.4 so it requires at least Angular-Slickgrid v5.6.4. The custom list would also require valid OperatorType, so adding custom operators simply won't be possible and adding a new operator is probably not useful with your use case anyway (that probably most won't help)
So anyway, I took another look at your problem and now understand that you want to filter against a local JSON dataset (not using a backend service). However, there's currently no way to provide a custom filter predicate at the moment and so I created this new PR to add this missing feature but that will only be available with Angular-Slickgrid 8.0 and higher (this will also only work with a local JSON dataset, it will not support backend services, at least not yet). I also think that you should use a regular text filter and not a compound filter, there's no need to change the operator, we just need to change the filter predicate.
With the next version (to be release next week to align with the upcoming Angular 18), you will be able to define a filterPredicate inside the column definition filter property as shown below
initializeGrid() {
  this.columnDefinitions = [
    {
      id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title', sortable: true, type: FieldType.string, filterable: true, 
      filter: {
        model: Filters.inputText,
        // you can use your own custom filter predicate when built-in filters aren't working for you
        filterPredicate: (dataContext, searchFilterArgs) => {
          const searchVals = (searchFilterArgs.parsedSearchTerms || []) as SearchTerm[];
          if (searchVals?.length) {
            const columnId = searchFilterArgs.columnId;
            const searchVal = searchVals[0] as string;
            const likeMatches = searchVal.split('%');
            if (likeMatches.length > 3) {
              // for matches like "%Ta%10%" will return text that starts with "Ta" and ends with "10" (e.g. "Task 10", "Task 110", "Task 210")
              const [_, start, end] = likeMatches;
              return dataContext[columnId].startsWith(start) && dataContext[columnId].endsWith(end);
            } else if (likeMatches.length > 2) {
              // for matches like "%Ta%10" will return text that starts with "Ta" and contains "10" (e.g. "Task 10", "Task 100", "Task 101")
              const [_, start, contain] = likeMatches;
              return dataContext[columnId].startsWith(start) && dataContext[columnId].includes(contain);
            }
            // for anything else we'll simply expect a Contains
            return dataContext[columnId].includes(searchVal);
          }
          // if we fall here then the value is not filtered out
          return true;
        } as any, // YOU WILL HAVE TO CAST IT TO `any` FOR OLDER VERSION since it doesn't currently exists
      },
    }
  ];
}

which gives the result shown below, note that the predicate is really crude and will probably need some improvements but it does the job to show how this will work future versions.

What if you are not ready to upgrade to Angular-Slickgrid 8.0?
In that case, with a bit of extra work, you could change the default filter used by the DataView. I don't recommend doing this (the recommendation is of course to upgrade whenever possible) but in your case that would be the only workable (temporary) solution. What we'll do is to get the current DataView filter predicate (assigned internally by Slickgrid-Universal) and patch it (for the version that you are currently using, you can copy the customLocalFilter() function and its code from Slickgrid-Universal v1.4 (for Angular-Slickgrid 4.x) and then apply the patch in your local code, something like below (I tested it and it works).
Note, below is a patched version of customLocalFilter() version, I only added the if condition as the updated patched code (uppercase console log below). Also note that I completely removed the code associated to Tree Data since I assume you are using a regular grid without a tree (but if you do use a Tree Data then add the missing code).
NOTE the code below was written and tested in Slickgrid-Universal, you will need to replace the this.sgb.dataView with Angular-Slickgrid related code something like this.angularGrid.dataView and use angularGridReady function as well.
patchDataViewFilter() {
  /** Local Grid Filter search */
  const filterServiceInstance = this.sgb.filterService;
  const customLocalFilter = (item: any, args: { columnFilters: ColumnFilters; dataView: SlickDataView; grid: SlickGrid; }) => {
    const grid = args?.grid;
    const columnFilters = args?.columnFilters ?? {};

    if (typeof columnFilters === 'object') {
      for (const columnId of Object.keys(columnFilters)) {
        const searchColFilter = columnFilters[columnId] as SearchColumnFilter;
        const columnFilterDef = searchColFilter.columnDef?.filter;

        // WE ARE ADDING A NEW "IF" CONDITION (the previous code only had the content of the "else")
        // user could provide a custom filter predicate on the column definition
        if (typeof columnFilterDef?.filterPredicate === 'function') {
          console.log('our filter predicate is reached!!!');
          const fpResult = columnFilterDef.filterPredicate(item, searchColFilter);
          if (!fpResult) {
            return false; // only return on false, when row is filtered out
          }
        } else {
          // THE "else" CODE CAME FROM THE ORIGINAL CODE
          const conditionOptions = filterServiceInstance.preProcessFilterConditionOnDataContext(item, searchColFilter, grid);

          if (typeof conditionOptions === 'boolean') {
            return conditionOptions;
          }

          let parsedSearchTerms = searchColFilter?.parsedSearchTerms; // parsed term could be a single value or an array of values

          // in the rare case that it's empty (it can happen when creating an external grid global search)
          // then get the parsed terms, once it's filled it typically won't ask for it anymore
          if (parsedSearchTerms === undefined) {
            parsedSearchTerms = getParsedSearchTermsByFieldType(searchColFilter.searchTerms, searchColFilter.columnDef.type || FieldType.string); // parsed term could be a single value or an array of values
            if (parsedSearchTerms !== undefined) {
              searchColFilter.parsedSearchTerms = parsedSearchTerms;
            }
          }

          // execute the filtering conditions check (all cell values vs search term(s))
          if (!FilterConditions.executeFilterConditionTest(conditionOptions as FilterConditionOption, parsedSearchTerms)) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // if it reaches here, that means the row is valid and passed all filter
    return true;
  };

  // override the filter predicate with ours
  this.sgb.dataView?.setFilter(customLocalFilter);
}

// then make sure to call it AFTER the grid is ready typically via `angularGridReady()`

and here's the proof that it worked and we reached our patched filter version. You can find the patched code I use in the PR but I will probably remove it before merging the PR, you can look at this commit before I remove it (it's the exact same code as above).

Another patch alternative could be to use something like pnpm patch or anything similar to patch the code directly at the source.
EDIT
Side note, in the original question, the search value is actually wrong if we want an SQL LIKE that starts with A and ends with B, then we should use Ti%001 instead of %Ti%001%. I also made the change in my demo and also switched to using regex in this PR and I follow this pattern match which is more accurate with SQL LIKE
const collection = ['Title 100.001', 'Title 100.002', 'Title 11.001', 'Title 1001.002'];
const searchVal1 = '%001';    // ends with 001
const searchVal2 = '%Ti%001'; // contains "Ti" + ends with 001
const searchVal3 = '%Ti%';    // contains "Ti"
const searchVal4 = 'Ti%001';  // combo starts with "Ti" + ends with 001
const searchVal5 = 'Ti%';     // starts with "Ti"
const searchVal6 = '%%';      // other
const searchVal7 = '100';     // other

EDIT 2
We should only call return when the filter predicate is false, otherwise our other column filters stop working because when we call return we are breaking the for loop for (const columnId of Object.keys(columnFilters)) { and that is why the next column filters stop working. In other words, when we return false, it stops further filters because there's no point in filtering anymore when the row is already being removed from consideration (filtered out).


Thank you, I am impressed with your help. I have two problems.

Not working: 'const searchVal = 'Ti%10%' // starts with 'Ti' + contains '10', but I'm trying to find a solution.
When I try to filter the second column, the filter does not work properly(nothing change); only one column works correctly.


ahh I forgot that when you use dataView.setFilter() it changes the filter for the entire grid, so make sure that you don't have any column specific code in the patched filter. Wow it's a good thing you told me, it looks like I have the same problem on my side with other columns. I'll have to investigate that one... and for the first filter, I'm using regex pattern now and I don't match exactly like you provided because I think it was wrong, for example we shouldn't have 3 % and I think that is wrong.

The first example, %Ti%001%, is incorrect, but the second example, Ti%10%, is correct (I'm frontend i made mistake :<). However, it's not currently working. I'm using your regex pattern too.

I'm sure that I didn't cover all use case of an SQL LIKE, because that is for demo purposes only, so yes you may need to adjust it some more. For the other problem, the issue was that we should return only when the predicate returns false, if the predicate returns true then we shouldn't call return inside the filter because that completely stops the filter loop and that's why the other column filters stops working. So just return only when predicate is false as shown above in my edit

for the regex, I had to adjust it a bit to have the contain from anywhere in the string, so here's the new regex. /^%([^%\r\n]+)[^%\r\n]*$|(.*)%(.+)%(.*)|(.+)%(.+)|([^%\r\n]+)%$/gi Both bug fix and regex fix are in this new PR, for the regex fix only see the 2nd commit here

Works perfectly. I have one suggestion: the default filter uses toLowerCase, maybe it's worth setting return dataContext[columnId].toLowerCase().endsWith(endW) etc. Thank you for your efforts

sure, but again it's just a demo :P  internally, the code is always evaluated as lowercase to be case insensitive. Anyway your suggestion is good and could be tweaked a bit more and define const cellValue = dataContext[columnId].toLowerCase(); and reuse cellValue to avoid duplicating dataContext[columnId].toLowerCase(); so many times. Side note, you accepted my answer but could also upvote it if it was useful.

I can't upvote your answer :(

ah yeah I think you need more reputation points yourself before you can upvote, I'm not sure why they do that (maybe to block bots), I upvoted your question to give you more reputation since it was a great question and thanks for the few ko-fi :)

it requires a reputation of 15, now that I upvoted your question you are at 17 reputation so you should be able to vote, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

I have an issue with a customFormatter. When I have a function that converts a number to a string, the filtering stops working.
{ id: 'type', name: 'Type', field: 'type', filterable: true, formatter: typeFormatter, type: FieldType.string, params: { useFormatterOuputToFilter: true }
then filterPredicated stop working

can't really help without a full repro, I would suggest you provide a repro directly in the project. I also don't monitor much of Stack Overflow comments

added an Edit 3 which should fix your issue, the answer is really that...well you need to handle it yourself!
